# Add more year on hierarchy slicer power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have a dashboard and it's connected with my sql database. On the table, the data already updated untill 12/31/2023. How can i add more year to my hierarchy slicer?

[image: 1]

I already try refresh the entire table, it's showed in preview table, but it's still stuck in hierarchy slicer.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a filter blocking more dates to appear on your report/slicer?

Comment: Thankyou, I didn't check 2023 year on the filter page, thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i didn't check 2023 year on the filter page.